# Add Remove rows in table as well as ADD REMOVE TABLES with same function as first table

Tags: jquery

Good Day All. Hope you are all well. I am trying to add remove tables with same function as first one. If you run my code below you will understand what I am saying. Please help, thank you.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- jquery cdn  -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery UI library -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <!--Added jspdf FROM - https://scotch.io/@nagasaiaytha/generate-pdf-from-html-using-jquery-and-jspdf-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>


    <!-- my css style  -->
    <style>
        .container {
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 5px #909090;
            margin-bottom: 5%;
        }

        .hrStyle {
            width: 100%;
            height: 3px;
            background-color: #444645;
        }

        .brStyle {
            margin: 5px 0;
        }

        select {
            border: 0;
        }

        select:hover {
            color: #444645;
            background: #ddd;
        }

        .thermoPic,
        .waterPic {
            height: 230px !important;
        }

        .pForDropDown {
            margin: 0 0 0 6px;
        }

        .bolding {
            font-weight: bolder;
        }

        * {
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        #addRow,
        #removeRow,
        #addTable,
        #removeTable {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // toggle to show and hide 2 logos 
            $(".thermoPic").click(function() {
                $(".waterPic").toggle();
            });

            $(".waterPic").click(function() {
                $(".thermoPic").toggle();
            });

            // automatic date for quote current date on reload 
            var d = new Date();
            document.getElementById("quoteDate").innerHTML = d.toDateString();

            // ADD ROW one at the time
            $("#addRow").click(function() {
                $("#tr").clone(true, true).insertAfter("#tr");
            });

            // Remove Row last child one at the time
            $("#removeRow").click(function() {
                $("#tr:last").remove();
            });

            // Add Table one at the time
            $("#addTable").click(function() {
                $("#TABLE").clone(true, true).insertAfter("#TABLE");
            });


            // Remove Table one at the time
            $("#removeTable").click(function() {
                $("#TABLE:last").remove();

            });
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body class="text-monospace">

    <div id="content" class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center font-weight-bolder text-dark bolding">Quotation</h1>
        <hr class="hrStyle"> <!-- ************line break*********** -->
        <div class="logoz d-flex justify-content-around">
            <img width="50%" class="thermoPic img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="#">
            <img width="50%" class="waterPic img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="#">
        </div> <!-- logoz  -->


        <hr class="hrStyle"> <!-- ************line break*********** -->

        <div class="quoteNumDate*">

            <div class="d-flex justify-content-left ">
                <span style="margin-right: 10px;">Quote Date: </span>
                <p id="quoteDate"></p>
            </div>

        </div> <!-- quoteNumDate  -->

        <hr class="hrStyle"> <!-- ************line break*********** -->

        <div class="ContractorDetails d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center*">
            <p class="pForDropDown">Contractor Details:</p>
            <select class="decorated">
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
            </select>

            <select class="decorated">
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
            </select>

            <select class="decorated">
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
            </select>

        </div> <!-- Contractor Details  -->


        <hr class="hrStyle"> <!-- ************line break*********** -->

        <div class="ResponsiblePerson d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center*">
            <p class="pForDropDown">Responsible Person:</p>
            <select class="decorated">
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
            </select>

            <select class="decorated">
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
            </select>

            <select class="decorated">
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
            </select>

        </div> <!-- ResponsiblePerson  -->

        <hr class="hrStyle"> <!-- ************line break*********** -->
        <br class="brStyle"> <!-- ************spacing*********** -->

        <div class="clientInfo">
            
            
        </div> <!-- class="clientInfo" -->

        <br class="brStyle"> <!-- ************spacing*********** -->
        <hr class="hrStyle"> <!-- ************line break*********** -->

        <p class="text-danger" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bolder;">
            All Prices are Excluding VAT
        </p>

        <hr class="hrStyle"> <!-- ************line break*********** -->
        <br class="brStyle"> <!-- ************spacing*********** -->

        <div class="first_table">

            <table class="table table-bordered text-center table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th contenteditable="true" scope="col">Actual Sqm Replacement Roof</th>
                        <th contenteditable="true" scope="col">Floor Area</th>
                        <th contenteditable="true" scope="col">Pitch %</th>
                        <th contenteditable="true" scope="col">Cover</th>
                        <th contenteditable="true" scope="col">Actual Lm</th>
                        <th contenteditable="true" scope="col">Sheet</th>
                        <th contenteditable="true" scope="col">Profile</th>
                        <th contenteditable="true" scope="col">Thickness</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th contenteditable="true" scope="row">write something here or delete</th>
                        <td contenteditable="true">10</td>
                        <td contenteditable="true">10</td>
                        <td contenteditable="true">10</td>
                        <td contenteditable="true">10</td>
                        <td contenteditable="true">10</td>
                        <td contenteditable="true">10</td>
                        <td contenteditable="true">10</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th contenteditable="true" scope="row">write something here or delete</th>
                        <td contenteditable="true">10</td>
                        <td contenteditable="true">10</td>
                        <td contenteditable="true">10</td>
                        <td contenteditable="true">10</td>
                        <td contenteditable="true">10</td>
                        <td contenteditable="true">10</td>
                        <td contenteditable="true">10</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div> <!-- first_table"  -->

        <br class="brStyle"> <!-- ************spacing*********** -->
        <hr class="hrStyle"> <!-- ************line break*********** -->

        <div id="table_container ">
            <span id="addTable">Table +</span>
            <span id="removeTable">Table -</span>
            <!-- JOB DESCRIPTIONS  -->
            <table id="TABLE" class="table table-bordered text-center user-details table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <span id="addRow">+</span>
                            <span id="removeRow">-</span>
                        </th>
                        <th contenteditable="true" scope="col">
                            <select>
                                <option></option>
                                <option>Ancillary Cost</option>
                                <option>Painting</option>
                                <option>Torch On</option>
                                <option>Sheet Replacement And Flashings</option>
                                <option>Purlins</option>
                                <option>Whirly Birds</option>
                                <option>Soco Sheets</option>
                                <option>Gutters And Downpipes</option>
                                <option>Alububble</option>
                                <option>Roof Fixings</option>
                                <option>Fiber Cemement Products</option>
                                <option>Crancks and Clips</option>
                            </select>
                        </th>
                        <th contenteditable="true" scope="col">Qty</th>
                        <th contenteditable="true" scope="col">Units</th>
                        <th contenteditable="true" scope="col">Rate Mat</th>
                        <th contenteditable="true" scope="col">Rate Lab</th>
                        <th contenteditable="true" scope="col">Total Mat</th>
                        <th contenteditable="true" scope="col">Total Lab</th>
                        <th contenteditable="true" scope="col">Total Cost</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="tr">
                        <td id="td">

                        </td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>





        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

It is not perfect code, but it will do for my company. I am trying to make the process of quotation with the least amount of typing as possible. Therefore less error. It is not finished yet, as soon as I complete it I will post the complete code again for your reference. Thanks again.

Comment: Please have a read of [mcve] - specifically the *minimal* part - and reduce the code in your question to just enough to demonstrate the problem, along with a *clear* statement of your problem with what you've tried.

Comment: You're also loading jquery twice

Comment: As well as duplicating IDs `$("#tr:last")`

Comment: i'll do next time. thanks

Comment: by adding table add remove from first table been cloned but it is not working

Comment: @freedomn-m any help please

Comment: Just some general points that will help you fix your issue: Use classes not IDs.  Use DOM navigation to find the relevant table, eg addRow click find the table that comes after the button then add a row to that table rather than just the first tr on the page.

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you so much i will do all what you said, hope you are always healthy. i'll let you know if i was successful.